# Dynamically allocating room for a pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, realloc

Can someone please explain this to me? Pointers have been the most confusing part of my current class I'm taking.

I have a struct that I want to contain an array of pointers to another struct `npc_t` like so

```
typedef struct dungeon {
  int num_monsters;
  struct npc_t *monsters;
} dungeon;
```

Then I want to dynamically allocate room for the array `monsters` when I initialize a new monster. I currently have

```
//add to dungeon's list of monsters
realloc(d->monsters, d->num_monsters);
d->monsters(d->num_monsters) = m;
d->num_monsters++;
```

where `num_monsters` is initialized to 0.

I get this message when I compile

```
npc.c: In function ‘init_monster’:
npc.c:65:13: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
  d->monsters(d->num_monsters) = m;
             ^
npc.c:64:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘realloc’, declared with    attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  realloc(d->monsters, d->num_monsters);
         ^
make: *** [npc.o] Error 1
```

Do I have the right idea on how I'm doing this? And can I use something like `d->monsters(d->num_monsters)` and `d->monsters(i)` to grab the monster I want? (if `i` were some increment in a for loop for example)

Comment: @Katana314 This question is not about C++.

Comment: Maybe you want `d->monsters[i]` instead of `d->monsters(i)` or `d- >monsters[d->num_monsters]` instead of `d- >monsters(d->num_monsters)`. Also, did you allocate memory for `d->monsters` earlier using `malloc`? If so, just check if `realloc` did not return `NULL`(which shows that it did not fail)

Comment: What are you trying to do here:`d->monsters(d->num_monsters)`? Try `d->monsters[d->num_monsters]`

Comment: Ok thanks, I was trying to do something like this `printf("*(p + %d) : %f\n",  i, *(p + i) );` which is from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_an_array.htm which I guess I know see I wasn't even doing that.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks, I'll add in the check. Do I need to malloc since the pointer is in a struct that I initialized? By initialize I mean I made an instance of it and I guess I thought that would allocate room for everything that's inside the struct.

Comment: It is a good practise to `malloc` and then `realloc` if more space is required. And use `d->monsters=realloc(d->monsters, d->num_ monsters);`.

Comment: Great thanks. I've made the changes and I'm getting an error that I'm not sure means. It says `invalid use of undefined type 'struct npc_t'` pointing at `d->monsters[d->num_monsters]` and `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` pointing at the same line but with the carrot at the first `[` Any hits on what this would be? To me everything looks good. I'm setting the pointer `monsters` at `d->num_monsters` to the address of `m` and `monsters` is a pointer itself.

Comment: If I get rid of the keyword `struct` in the `dungeon struct` I get this error instead `incompatible types when assigning to type 'npc_t' from type 'struct npc_t *'` And this is pointing at the `=` now

Comment: Sorry for so many comments. May have found a solution. I dereferenced the pointer `m` and now I compile without error. Would this be the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
realloc(d->monsters, d->num_monsters);
```

should be:

```
d->monsters = realloc(d->monsters, d->num_monsters * sizeof *d->monsters);
```

That `sizeof` is *super important*, without it you're under-allocating by a large amount which will lead to undefined behavior as your code writes outside the allocated storage.

Also, the proper array indexing syntax is `a[i]`, parentheses are for function call.

Answer (score 4):

This line :

```
d->monsters(d->num_monsters) = m;
```

is the biggest source of your problems.
Basically, you are trying to run a function called 'monsters' inside d.
Also, the compiler tells you there is no such function.

You should have used [ ] instead of (), which was your intention of picking up an element from your array of monsters.

But then, after the realloc, the array of monsters have only {d -> num_monsters} elements.

Also, you can't access the element [n] in an array of n elements, so this line :

```
d->monsters[d->num_monsters] = m;
```

will not work.
But this will do :

```
d->monsters[d->num_monsters - 1] = m;
```

Comment: Forgot that the realloc ask for a number of **bytes** and **not elements**, typed with _size_t_ . Look for unwind's answer for the fix.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm reallocating the array to `d->num_monsters` so that I can insert `m` at the end of the array